# Add something like a description or specification to a database field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im new to sql and rails. I actually trying to develop a simple application that can exchange data with another website that provides maps. 
I have for example a `longitud` field in my database:

```
t.string :longitud
```

The thing is that i would like to add something like a description to this database migration because on the server of this map provider `longitud` has to be passed as the `3100` field.

I now that i can define a default in my migration for example:

```
t.string :longitud, default => 'east'
```

But can i also pass something like a description? Thanks

```
 t.string :longitud, description => `3100`
```

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid but I don't understand why you need this 'description' ?

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting to describe the API in the database perhaps? How about creating an interim model for API interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrations do not support a description field.

If you need it accessible in your code, to determine what field it maps to, you will need to create a separate model to represent the mappings.

If it is just for your own documentation, then you could add comments to your model describing each field.